# Azure sample application is not working when trying to run in emulator

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am running a azure storage program.

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/web-site-with-storage/

When I am running the application I am getting an error:

```
    throw err;
          ^
```

Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT
    at errnoException (dns.js:31:11)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:140:16)

I have edited the program to use the emulator with credentials as:
  , accountName = 'azure.ServiceClient.DEVSTORE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT'
  , accountKey = 'azure.ServiceClient.DEVSTORE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY';

/**

can you please let me know what is the issue and how to get around this

@smarx help me identifying that it is a problem with account settings.

can you please let me know how to get around this

Comment: What happens when you run it in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

I met with a similar problem when using the storage against local emulator. Not sure if this helps but when I specified the local table service endpoint it worked. The code looks like

`var client = azure.createTableService(azure.ServiceClient.DEVSTORE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT, azure.ServiceClient.DEVSTORE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY, azure.ServiceClient.DEVSTORE_TABLE_HOST);`

Comment: I still get the same Error : I have added :  azure.createTableService(accountName, accountKey,accounthost) and ,accounthost = 'azure.ServiceClient.DEVSTORE_TABLE_HOST'; in var declaration list

Comment: When specifying the account, key and host, was your code looks like var key = 'azure.ServiceClient.DEVSTORE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT'? Or var key = azure.ServiceClient.DEVSTORE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT ? You should not quote them by single quotes.